# how to find and erase item from vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<User*> myFriends_;
```

Then I have code to see if the element `theFriend` exists in the vector.

```
if (std::find(myFriends_.begin(), myFriends_.end(), theFriend)!=myFriends_.end())
            return FAILURE;
```

I would like to do some thing like

```
User* toErease;
toErease=std::find(myFriends_.begin(), myFriends_.end(), theFriend);
if (toErease!=myFriends_.end())
                return FAILURE;
myFriends_.erase(toErease); /// remove this element if its precent
```

Will it work?

`find` returns the location of the element

And `erase` needs the index as far as I know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom

Comment: Call `std::vector::erase` with the iterator returned by `std::find`.

Comment: `theFriend)!=myFriends_.end()` isn't an appropriate predicate. Put that into a lambda function, or functor class. Also [`remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) might help for simplifying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::find(myFriends_.begin(), myFriends_.end(), theFriend);
```

returns an iterator of type `std::vector<User*>::iterator`

So, you need to have

```
std::vector<User*>::iterator toErease ;

toErease=std::find(myFriends_.begin(), myFriends_.end(), theFriend);

// And then erase if found
if (toErease!=myFriends_.end())
{
   /* Since container element is a pointer to User
      you need to destroy it too ! */
   delete *toErease ;

   myFriends_.erase(toErease);
   //... return SUCCESS ;
}
return FAILURE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean the following

```
User *theFriend = new User( /*...*/ );
//...
auto it = std::find_if( myFriends_.begin(), myFriends_.end(), 
                        [&]( User *user ) { return *user == *theFriend; } );

if ( it != myFriends_.end() )
{
   delete *it;
   myFriends_.erase( it );
}
```

Take into account that either class User shall have `operator ==` or you should use some other lambda expression that to compare users by some criteria.

Comment: if OP wants to delete the element, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Jarod42 It is not an answer to the question. It is an answer to a question something like how better to define a vector of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Effective STL book advise in his item 33 p 120 to be aware remove-like algorithms on containers of pointers and advise to use containers of smart pointers instead of containers of raw pointers.
An example of code based on the erase remove idiom for your case will be as follows.

1. Declare a function to check the presence of theFriend in the vector and delete it ( functor will be more appropriate):

   void delAndNullifyFirend(User*& pUser`){//check the presence of theFriends and delete}

`

```
for_each(myFriends_.begin(),myFriends_.end(), delAndNullifyFirend);`
myFriends_.erase(remove(myFriends_.begin(),myFriends_.end(),static_cast<User*>(0)),
                     myFriends_.end());
```